# Has anyone been irked by titles starting with "Has anyone ..."?

Tags: feature-request, question-titles

[Well, *has* anyone??](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3A%22has+anyone%22) ([Part 2](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3A%22has+anybody%22).)

---

Okay, but seriously.

- [Has Anyone Used ISPconfig 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215506/has-anyone-used-ispconfig-3?s=1|6.2134)
- [Has anyone installed Real Player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277339/has-anyone-installed-real-player?s=2|6.0594)
- [Has anyone compiled eSpeak Text-to-Speech?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69375/has-anyone-compiled-espeak-text-to-speech?s=4|5.2918)
- [Has anyone successfully installed Syspro on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588429/has-anyone-successfully-installed-syspro-on-ubuntu?s=5|5.2779)
- [Has anyone successfully installed ubuntu on a Lenovo Y410P](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433792/has-anyone-successfully-installed-ubuntu-on-a-lenovo-y410p?s=15|4.3982)

I don't know, man, *has* anyone, or *haven't* they?

---

AU is not a *forum* for *discussion*; we come here to get *objective* answers to *real* questions, not to make (gnu) smalltalk. Moreover, these sorts of questions get closed as primarily opinion-based because they tend to ask for opinions.

Granted, AU is far from the only site with this antipattern in titles.

- [Has anyone played an mp3 file on a RaspberryPi3 and streamed the output to a bluetooth speaker?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/44086/39295) (raspberrypi.se)
- [Has anyone used UXCam before? [on hold]](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/91370/77024) (ux.se)
- [Has anyone statistics for the number of users completing a registration for a service?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/88023/77024) (ux.se)

---

Maybe it's just me, but these kinds of titles seem *chit-chatty*, and they add to the chit-chattyness of the question following said title; rather than asking an *actual* question these titles seem to beg a discussion about the weather.

I'm always tempted to retitle these questions, but coming up with a good title for such a post that accurately divulges the content should be the job of the *asker*, not *me* (or other editors).

I'd like to request "Has anyone" and "Has anybody" be added to the list of terms in titles that raise [a "warning" dialogue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300740/can-stack-overflow-notice-a-regular-expression-question-and-maybe-suggest-someth)<sup>1</sup> beside the title box when it loses focus.

---

<sup>1</sup>Not the sort of dialogue that prevents the question from being posted, but merely informatic (Clippy, anyone?) that such titles aren't preferred over actually helpful, descriptive titles, and perhaps a link to [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/310919).

An example of the text in the dialogue could be:

> Please avoid informalities like "Can someone" and "Has anyone...?" in question titles. **If your motivation for asking is “I would like to participate in a discussion about this subject”, then you should not be asking here.** Read more about what makes a question on-topic and constructive in the help center:
>
> - [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask)
> - [What kinds of questions are on-topic here?](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I think this is a really good idea. I was lamenting about this just earlier today. We'd need to come up with a proposed wording for the dialogue.

Comment: @Seth Yaay, a mod agrees! I was ambivalent about how well-recieved this post would be. I'll add an idea for the dialogue to the question.

Comment: Just for the sake of numbers: https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/450735.

Comment: +1 For another "Has anyone"

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Has anyone looked into actually helping put an end to the "has anyone"s?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree that such titles need improvement. But looking at the data, I do not find much indication that the OP wants to participate in a broad discussion. Most often, it's just poor writing form: writing "Has anyone successfully installed (this) on (that)" when the actual question is how to install that thing.

Another, strongly related, mistake is writing something like "Can anyone help me with this wireless driver problem" instead of actually describing the problem. It's not conversational style that's the main issue, but lack of specifics.

I dug up some stats:

- [think](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3A%22think%22): 91 questions (nearly all low-quality)
- [Can someone](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3A%22can+someone%22): 70 questions
- [Can anyone](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3A%22can+anyone%22): 57
- [Does anyone](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3A%22does+anyone%22): 44
- [Has anyone](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3A%22has+anyone%22): 36
- [Can anybody](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3A%22can+anybody%22): 16
- [Does anybody](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3A%22does+anybody%22): 14
- [Does someone](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3A%22does+someone%22): 5
- [Has anybody](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3A%22has+anybody%22): 5

All of these are dwarfed by

- [please help](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3A%22please+help%22): 271 questions. As in "update problem, please help"...

So, I suggest addressing this wider problem of insufficiently specific titles. A title matching

```
^.{0,30}(^|\W)(anybody|anyone|doubt|help|please|problem|question|somebody|someone|think)(\W|$).{0,30}$
```

<sup>case insensitive, in whichever flavour</sup>

probably needs work and should generate a warning message, like the one on [Math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/17012).

[Test above regex here](https://regex101.com/r/eW6rT9/1).

Comment: Oooh, I *like* this. Probably the `the question you're asking appears (subjective|off-topic) and is likely to be closed` is better than the suggestion in my question.

Comment: you're right, of course, but I still feel like the reaction of "I don't know. Can someone? Who knows? Not AskUbuntu." to titles like that makes them classifiable as asking for opinions even if the question doesn't.

Comment: You just need to throw out the ones that aren't unanswered and this would be a great list for editors to sort through. EDIT: toss out the duplicates too!

Comment: @404 What about http://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3A%22think%22 ? That's worse than I was expecting when I searched for it

Comment: @JorgeCastro most of them, a single downvote does the trick

Comment: Can anyone help me think about my problem, please?  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby which problem?

Comment: @tac: That's why there is a smiley: most OPs need help *thinking*...  **:D** But thanks for offering to help me think, but I'm overflowing with thoughts already!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby *oh* I so didn't get the joke the first time. :P but yes, I agree :)